# VIsual Studio - Custom Solution Configuration with Debugging

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I want to set a Custom Configuration that works with Debugging.

Let's say i am programming a clientside application, and a colleague the serverside one. Now when he is coding, i cannot test my client app, except when there is a server app running on the server with a different port number.
So for my application, i have to do something like

```
#if (DEBUG)
    portNumber = 1234;
#elif (RELEASE)
    portNumber = 4321;
```

But there is no way to Debug throught Release Builds. So i need to implement a new state: (DEBUG_LiveSystem) and do something like

```
#if (DEBUG)
    portNumber = 1234;
#elif (DEBUG_LiveSystem)
    portNumber = 4321;
#elif (RELEASE)
    portNumber = 4321;
```

So i need to enable Debugging for the state DEBUG_LiveSystem.
Is there a way to do this?
I hope i explained it good enought to understand what i mean.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own symbols like this:

```
#define DEBUG
//#define TRACE
#undef TRACE

using System;

public class TestDefine
{
    static void Main()
    {
#if (DEBUG)
        Console.WriteLine("Debugging is enabled.");
#endif

#if (TRACE)
     Console.WriteLine("Tracing is enabled.");
#endif
    }
}
```

You can find more information on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x.aspx) MSDN page.

Comment: So am I able to switch the states inside the solutions configurations?
Well thats what i want, and not commenting a line inside a class in my code